# Does clamd from clamav automatically scan the system by default?

Tags: linux, debian, clamav

I'm want to know this because i want to know if it's necessary to setup a cronjob with clamav or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know: no. This is what [help for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV#Run_ClamAV_as_a_Daemon) (and I don't see my Debian being far from this) says about the daemon:

> You can then use `clamdscan` where you would previously have used `clamscan`. Lots of programs, especially e-mail servers, can connect to a ClamAV daemon. This speeds up virus scanning as the program is always in memory.

It looks like scans are on-demand. The daemon waits to do its job for any program that asks.

There is, however [ClamFS](http://clamfs.sourceforge.net/):

> a FUSE-based user-space file system for Linux with on-access anti-virus file scanning through `clamd` daemon.

But keep in mind this is FUSE, so read [these security concerns](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html).